# Why "///www.example.com" is treated as an absolute URI?

Tags: url, browser, path, uri

html code:
`<a href="///www.example.com">Test</a>`

I wonder why this is legal in chrome, and the link `www.example.com` but not `current.com///www.example.com` is opened. Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the absolute URI to be? What do you mean with "abstract path"? Do you ask if this is a valid URI? If so, what is the relation to Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [RFC 3986 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5) for the official rules governing how URL links are resolved.